# Scale uniform interval estimator

Tags: confidence-interval, uniform-distribution

I have a problem with the scale uniform interval estimator (Example 9.1.6, page 419, Casella-Berger).  Let $X_1,\dots,X_n \sim \text{IID U}(0,\theta)$ be our observed data.  We are interested in an interval estimator of $\theta$.

Consider the interval estimator $[Y + c; Y + d]$   where $Y = \max (X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and $0<c<d$ (note that $\theta$ is necessarily larger than $y$).  I have no problem with the solution but I don't understand why we consider the interval $Y + c$ instead of $Y -c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be 0 $\le$ c $<$ d for $[Y + c; Y + d]$, and $1 \le a < b$ for $[aY;bY]$, $0 < a < b$ doesn't make sense for any of these. Since $0 < x < \theta$ consequently $0 < max(x_1,\dots,x_n) < \theta$ then $0 < y < \theta$. Also $a0 < ay < a\theta$ shows that the minor value that 'a' can assume is 1 to preserve $0 < y < \theta$, and 'b' needs to be greater then 'a' so the interval makes sense, hence we have $1 \le a < b$ for $[aY;bY]$. Using the same logic for $[Y + c; Y + d]$ you will get $0\le c < d$. So, if $d > c$ and $\theta$ is larger then $Y$, you already have the basic relations you need for a possible interval where $Y + c < Y + d$, if intead you take $Y - c < Y + d$, you will work with desnecessary informations since you are trying to increase the size of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but if $Y=\max_i X_i$, then the upper limit of the uniform distribution $\theta$ necessarily must be $\theta \ge Y$.  Hence looking for anything less than $Y$ does not make sense...

I am not familiar with this particular problem, but it seems to be a continuous version of the well known "German Tank Problem".

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is not really a solution at all, since there is no specification of how you get $c$ and $d$ from the observed data.  At the moment the "solution" is merely saying that the interval estimator will a lower bound that is above $y$.  You have already noted in your question that $\theta$ is always larger than $y$, so obviously it makes sense to use an interval of this form.

The next step in solving the problem would be to specify $c$ and $d$ as functions of the data so that you get a specific interval estimate for a given set of data.  The standard way to do this would be to use the sufficient statistic $Y$ to form a ["pivotal quantity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity) that can be used to form an appropriate [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval).  In any case, however you form the interval estimator, you will want to check that it has good statistical properties (e.g., correct coverage probability, consistency, etc.).